# How to conditional format with dynamic references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight all the cells containing a formula error or formulas
followed the below steps

1. Did a CTRL+A and selected all the cells
2. Home > Conditional Formatting > Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Applied the formula ***=OR(ISERROR(A1),ISFORMULA(A1))***
4. Selected a fill colour and clicked on ok

Expectation: All the cells which is having a formula or error value like #N/A need to be selected.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: I am guessing the active cell in the selection is not `A1`. To avoid that you can change to R1C1 reference type in the Excel Formula Options, and use `RC` instead of `A1`

Comment: sure @pnuts that's much simpler if the active cell is the issue

Comment: @Slai i took your advice on the active cell. In my case A1 was hidden and not active and that was the culprit. I have gone with ISERROR in the formula because for some reason "Find & Select" is not able to find #N/A as a formula error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formulas in conditional formatting work with reference to the active cell in the selection. In the example given below I have selected `B2` to `E6` with the active cell as `C3` and then applied the conditional formatting.

[image: Example Conditional formatting]

In the example above in the selection `B1` to `E6` the active cell is `C3`. Now when you use `=ISERROR(D4)`, it is effectively applying it to `R[-1]C[-1]` because you are checking the value in `D4` according to the formula and applying it on the selected cell i.e. `C3` as you can see in the image.

Thus if you now put `#N/A` in Cell `D4`, Cell `C3` will become Orange

If instead the active cell in the selection was `D4` instead of `C3` then the conditional formatting would highlight all `#N/A`

If you want to understand clearly, try `=ISERROR($D$4)` and put a `#N/A` in `D4`, that will highlight all the cells `B2:E6`.

Else you can also go to

- File>Options>Formulas and check R1C1 reference style

Comment: Thanks this worked for formula error. Is there a way to highlight the cells with formula like SUM or AVERAGE etc

Comment: @pnuts I wanted to make the answer a bit more generalized to the audience because of which I changed the question title and changed the answer with a simple example. I am sure that the person who asked the question will understand that he/she is supposed not supposed to use the exact formula that I have used in my example.

Comment: Actually that comment was for a version of my answer that was completely different. In that answer I was explaining how to conditionally formal only cells that contain errors without formulas, if you know what I mean. @Charity understood that it will solve the current problem but is not a generalized solution, hence the comment